# Volley times out before retry policy's initial timeout

Tags: android, timeout, android-volley

I'm making a post request using volley with a custom retry policy.

The socket timeout is 30000ms. My server is receiving the post request ,however volley throws a timeout error before 30sec for some reason.

My server load time is about 5500ms including latency.
My custom retry policy looks like this:

```
RETRY POLICY

public RetryPolicy getGembaRetryPolicy(){
    DefaultRetryPolicy defaultRetryPolicy = new DefaultRetryPolicy(
            30000,
            0,
            1f);

    return defaultRetryPolicy;
}
```

30000 being SOCKET_TIMEOUT_IN_MS

0 being RETRIES

1f BACKOFF_MULT

CUSTOM REQUEST CLASS:

```
public class CustomJSONObjectRequest extends JsonObjectRequest {

public String authKey = null;
private Map<String, String> params;

public CustomJSONObjectRequest(int method, String url, JSONObject jsonRequest,
                               Response.Listener<JSONObject> listener,
                               Response.ErrorListener errorListener, String authKey) {
    super(method, url, jsonRequest, listener, errorListener);
    this.authKey = authKey;

}


protected Map<String, String> getParams()
        throws AuthFailureError {

    return params;
}

@Override
protected VolleyError parseNetworkError(VolleyError volleyError){
    if(volleyError.networkResponse != null && volleyError.networkResponse.data != null){
        VolleyError error = new VolleyError(new String(volleyError.networkResponse.data) + authKey);
        volleyError = error;
    }

    return volleyError;
}

public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
    HashMap<String, String> headers = new HashMap<String, String>();
    headers.put("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=utf-8");

    if (authKey != null) {
        headers.put("Authorization", "Token " + authKey);
        Log.d("AUTH_KEY:", authKey);
    }


    return headers;
}

@Override
public RetryPolicy getRetryPolicy() {
    return AppInstance.getInstance().getGembaRetryPolicy();
}
}
```

APPINSTANCE:

```
public class AppInstance extends MultiDexApplication {

public static  Typeface RobotoRegular;
public static Typeface RobotoLight;

private static AppInstance instance;
public static AppInstance getInstance() {
    return instance;
}

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();

    Fabric.with(this, new Crashlytics());

    instance = this;

    RobotoRegular = Typeface.create("sans-serif", Typeface.NORMAL);

    RobotoLight=Typeface.create("sans-serif-light", Typeface.NORMAL);

    RealmManager.getInstance(getApplicationContext());

    Realm realm = Realm.getInstance(getApplicationContext());

}

@Override
protected void attachBaseContext(Context base) {
    super.attachBaseContext(base);
    MultiDex.install(this);
}

public RetryPolicy getGembaRetryPolicy(){
    DefaultRetryPolicy defaultRetryPolicy = new DefaultRetryPolicy(
            IBotConstants.SOCKET_TIMEOUT_IN_MS,
            IBotConstants.RETRIES,
            DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_BACKOFF_MULT);

    return defaultRetryPolicy;
}

}
```

Finally I'm adding the request to the queue:

```
jsonRequest = new CustomJSONObjectRequest(method, url, json, this, this, authKey);
        mQueue.add(jsonRequest);
```

Comment: Where are you setting the RequestTimeOut policy?

Comment: In my CustomJSONObjectRequest I've overridden public RetryPolicy getRetryPolicy()